# Primefaces CSS Not Working p:selectOneMenu & p:calender

Tags: primefaces

Primefaces CSS is not working in `p:selectOneMenu`  and `p:calendor` component.
When I am giving `style="width:190px;"` 
it's taking, but when I am using style Class it is not taking.

[image: see the below...]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

for `p:Calendar`override following css:

```
.ui-inputfield, .ui-widget-content .ui-inputfield, .ui-widget-header .ui-inputfield {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 2px #D3D3D3 inset;
    color: #555555;
    width: 190px!important;
}
```

for `p:selectOneMenu` add following css:

```
.dropdownWidth{
        width:190px !important;
    }
```

and add `styleClass="dropdownWidth"` for your `p:selectOneMenu` component

Answer (score 0):

Use your browsers developer tools (in Chrome, hit F12 or right click the element and select "Inspect element") to see if there are any other CSS classes that are setting the width, you may have a pre-existing class that is setting the width that would be superseded by in-line styles but not by a class with a less specific identifier.

Comment: What isn't working? The developer tools themselves or the potential CSS changes?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the size option to determine the width of the input element.
like this :

```
<p:calendar id="dateNaissance" value="#{utilisateurController.selected.dateNaissance}" 
showOn="button" size="32" />
```